# AngularJS issue when its uses materialize carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, materialize, phonegap

I have a mobile application made with angularJs and materialize css.

Its uses API for showing data and its packed with phone gap.

I am putting down my main issue with this app. If any of you guys help me i will be thankfull to you guys.

when i am using this code in app, its load but not showing in

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item" ng-repeat="x in campList">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                <img class=" materialboxed" src="my-api-source-link/images/slider/{{x.myphoto}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and there is the proof of its loading in browser

This Photo >>

[image]

When i am using without materialize carousel, its loading and showing.

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="x in campList">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
        <img class=" materialboxed" src="my-api-source-link/images/slider/{{x.myphoto}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

- myphoto tag (or thing) comes from json data.
- project have controllers and .tpl files. All working correct but i have this issue
- its my first angularjs project. Little explanation will help me lot